# <text_file.txt>:File or directory not found

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am working on a BASHScript to start wlan monitor mode without interefering with NetworkManager and I am having trouble with this function:

```
serial_setup(){

local file_name=$1
while IFS =, read PhysicalDevice ItfAlias ItfMode;
do
iw $PhysicalDevice interface add $ItfAlias type $ItfMode
ifconfig $ItfAlias up
done < file_name

}
```

The above function reads a textfile in format:

```
PhysicalDevice1,alias1,mode1
PhysicalDevice2,alias2,mode2
PhysicalDevice3,alias3,mode3
```

I need to find out the cause of error and optimum solution?

**EDIT:** Here is the full code: [MM Script](http://pastebin.com/si4K1S5i)
I have to use paste`bin due to trouble pasting and formatting the code here

Comment: how do you call / launch the bash script?

Comment: well: ./myscript.sh <command_to_activate _the_fuction> <file_name>.Note;script and file both are in same directory

Comment: It's really not helpful to obfuscate your input like `<text_file.txt>` and `<command_to_activate _the_fuction>` IMHO: show us what you're **actually** typing and the **actual** error that occurs. FWIW it looks like you're trying to call a function from a script by passing its name as the first argument to the script - I'm not aware that that works (at least not in bash): either *source* your script so that the function becomes available in the current shell, or add a line to your script itself that calls the function with the script's first argument.

Comment: And please double-check that you are showing us an *exact, accurate* representation of your script. There are at least a couple of trivial typos in the script in your question.  I suspect that they are typos in the question only, and they're not really in the script, but it would be nice to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if you have forgotten a `$` on a variable. You have also forgotten to double-quote several other variables:

```
serial_setup () {
    local file_name="$1"

    while IFS=, read PhysicalDevice ItfAlias ItfMode; do
        iw "$PhysicalDevice" interface add "$ItfAlias" type "$ItfMode"
        ifconfig "$ItfAlias" up
    done <"$file_name"
}
```

See "[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)".

Comment: hmm..sir its still not working after performing eadits as per your suggestions

Comment: @Xasel You also had a space between `IFS` and `=,` that I didn't spot at first. For the future, never say _it doesn't work_, describe what's happening and what you had expected would happen. It makes it easier to help.

Comment: UH atlast,this was the root of all problem(no pun intneded),thank you sire for correcting me out.Most of the tutorials that I referred to doesn't enlist nuances as such.Therefore I am deciding to buy a dedicated book  on BAsh Intrenals.Can you suggest some good ones as per your experience?

Comment: @Xasel No, sorry I can't. I've never used a shell scripting book. I've only looked at working examples and at the manual (`man bash`).